# How to plot 3D data with same colormap for both positive and negative range?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want a 3D plot from a csv file, for which I want to have a colormap representing the distance moved relatively from the center. So I want the colors to be same for both positive and negative values, for eg: yellow for 10 and -10.

Also I want the label the colorbar with the absolute values ignoring the signs.

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
A = csvread('some.csv');
x=A(:,1);
y=A(:,2);
z=A(:,3);
c = linspace(1,10,length(A(:,1)));
sz = 25;
% scatter3(x, y, z);

tri = delaunay(x, y, z);
trisurf(tri, x, y, z)


colorbar;

shading interp 
title('some title');
xlabel('x in mm');  
ylabel('y in mm');
zlabel('z in mm');

colorbar('YTickLabel',...
{'30','20','10','0',...
 '10','20','30'})
```

I have manually assigned labels with absolute values, but I want to know if this can be done automatically using the range of values from the csv file.

Please help me in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your colormap and relabel the colorbar

```
curMap = colormap;
colormap([curMap(end:-1:1,:); curMap ])

colorbar_h = colorbar;
set(colorbar_h, 'yTickLabel', abs(str2double(get(colorbar_h', 'yTickLabel'))))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I had to use str2num instead of str2double. Its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

`trisurf` allows you to specify the colors that you want as the fifth argument, so

```
trisurf(tri, x, y, z, abs(z))
```

will get you what you want. No need to relabel the colorbar.

Comment: This is not I am expecting, but I want 0 at the middle of the bar and distance on the either from center with same color for same values on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own colormap!

You are now using the default one, but you can choose:

```
cm=colormap('parula');
```

Now lets modify it and set it

```
cm=[flipud(cm);cm];
colormap(cm);
```

Test:

```
peaks
colorbar
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCuRn.png

Comment: (SO is rejecting my image uploads, so for now click the link :S)